# Unknown data_format

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to run the ENAS (Efficient Neural Architecture Search via Parameter Sharing) project and I am blocked by this error : File "/enas-add-license-1/enas-add-license-1/src/cifar10/micro_child.py", line 258, in _model
raise ValueError("Unknown data_format '{0}'".format(self.data_format))
ValueError: Unknown data_format 'NHWC'
I would like to know if it is a problem with my environment. I use python 3.6 and tensorflow 1.13.2 or something else.

Comment: the problem is that you tried to supply some data in what (at any rate in your env) is an invalid format.  I have no idea what ENAS and NHWC are, but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/melodyguan/enas/issues/103) suggesting this might be due to a typo in the source; I'm afraid I can't help further

Comment: Hi! Could you share a standalone code to reproduce this . Have you tried the same in latest version TF 2.6 yet?